# C++ template specialization without template<>

Tags: c++

I have two versions of program. First:

```
template<class T>
void f(T i, T j) = delete;

template<>
void f(int i, int j) {
    cout << i << j << endl;
};

int main()
{
    f(1.5, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

And second:

```
template<class T>
void f(T i, T j) = delete;

void f(int i, int j) {
    cout << i << j << endl;
};

int main()
{
    f(1.5, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

The first version won't compile because `1.5` and `2` have different types. In the second version I removed `template<>` so `1.5` will be converted to `1` and program will run successfully.
So, when we remove `template<>`, is it still template specialization, or is it something else? Is there any difference besides implicit type casting? Is it useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a (unqualified) function invocation as `f(1.5, 2)` in your code the compiler builds a set of candidate functions which contains regular functions and functions generated from templates. A function template is not a function until the template arguments have been resolved and substituted. See [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) for full details.

`f` is function template and it cannot deduce `T` from arguments of type `double` and `int`. The template specialization isn't considered because template argument deduction failed. The viable set of functions is empty and the compilation fails to compile the call.

You can resolve `T` ambiguity for the compiler if you call it as `f<int>` but such a call considers `f` templates only (because you explicitly specify the template parameter).

If you make the full specialization of `f` not a template, it becomes an regular function. In this case the template argument deduction still fails as before, but now there is another function `f` and the set of candidate functions contains that one function `f`. It can be called with the supplied arguments because `double` is implicitly converted to `int`.

For functions parameters whose types aren't deduced from the argument types (i.e. the parameter type is not a template parameter or an explicitly specified template parameter) the compiler considers implicit conversion of argument types to function parameter types and `double` to `int` is in implicit conversion and that's why the call to overloaded function `f` succeeds.

Comment: I want to stress that the problem does not come from the function being a template but from the automatically resulting ambiguity. You would have the same problem if you have an additional (non-template) `void f(double, double)` function because then there would be ambiguity again.

Comment: @BlameTheBits there are many ways to arrive at the same problem, the answer is about the path chosen by OP ;)

Comment: The answer's correct of course, but I wonder if the last part of the question could be addressed? i.e. is there any benefit to the non-template overload other than allowing implicit conversions?

Comment: @cigien The template resolution fails and that's why the template function cannot be used. Added a note about regular functions.

Comment: No, I meant the last bit of the question asking if there is any benefit to a regular function *other* than implicit conversions.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That may be the case although I cannot think of something else right now. My point also was not about invalidating your answer. I was just concerned about the assumption the OP seem to have come up with that with 'normal' functions there would always be an implicit cast and that you cannot run into the same ambiguity problem with them. (That is why I find your last paragraph misleading btw.)

Comment: @BlameTheBits The error with the first piece of code is due to template argument deduction failure. The ambiguity with argument conversions you mention doesn't come into play yet because the candidate function set is empty.